# Changing caption in Dyalog APL

Tags: string, properties, assign, apl, dyalog

I'm working in Dyalog APL version 17.0 and I'm having some trouble getting a line to execute:

```
SYNTAX ERROR
switch[10] ('CP.B',(⍕zloc),'.Caption')←capt
                                      ∧
```

`capt` is a character vector, and `zloc` is a scalar number. I know a lot of people don't use this language, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're meaning to imitate executing `CP.B_.Caption←capt` for a given number replacing the underscore, this would work:

```apl
⍎'CP.B',(⍕zloc),'.Caption←capt'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3zlA4VHbBIVHfVP9gh/1ruFyDtBzMgaKoAroOScWlGTm5wEl1NPy89W5uIDyQA6KJBdXVU5@MlDUmCsZKAJSm5RYpM71qLdPHaRQXUfjUe9UkBpNHXUkE0GKsZv4/z8A)

You're trying to assign a vector to to an unnamed character vector, which isn't valid in APL. This code, instead, evaluates a full APL expression.

If possible, however, storing `CP`'s contents as an array would be much better.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're changing the `Caption` property of a GUI object.

You can do so with `⎕WS` (Window Set property):

```
('CP.B',⍕zloc) ⎕WS 'Caption' capt
```